# Print on same line at the first in python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are several solutions for printing on same line and at the first of it, like below.

In python 2,

```
print "\r Running... xxx",
```

And in Python 3,

```
print("\r Running... xxx", end="")
```

I can't find a single print solution to cover python 2 and 3 at the same time. Do I have to use `sys.stdout.write`?

Comment: Since `print` is a **statement** in Python 2, you'd not use the parentheses.

Comment: Why not making a line string concatenating the partial strings you want in the same line?  print("%s%s%s) % (string_1, string_2, string_3)

Comment: @Trimax: perhaps your process runs too slow for that and you want to provide feedback?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for pointing out about parentheses!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `from __future__ import print_function` and use the `print()` function in both Python 2 and Python 3:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print("\r Running... xxx", end="")  # works across both major versions
```

See the [`print()` function documentation in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print):

> **Note**: This function is not normally available as a built-in since the name print is recognized as the print statement. To disable the statement and use the `print()` function, use this future statement at the top of your module:
>
> ```
> from __future__ import print_function
> ```

The `print()` function was added to Python 2.6.

Comment: It works. But `sys.stdout.flush()` is still needed to flush output buffer. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: No, only the version in Python 3.3 and up offers a `flush` keyword. You can provide your own wrapper that adds a flush call.

Comment: @lqez: anything you wanted me to clarify? You accepted, then unaccepted again, something I missed?

Comment: Nope, i just unaccepted it to ask you about flushing. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

in Python 2 and use print as a function in Python 2 also

```
print("\r Running... xxx", end="")
```