# from __future__ import print_function not working as intended

Tags: python, python-2.x

I've used the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732163/print-on-same-line-at-the-first-in-python-2-and-3) to print in the same line in Python 2.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time

num = '\r'
for i in xrange(10):
    num += str(i+1) + ' '
    print (num, end='')
    time.sleep(0.3)
print('\n')
```

But it only prints the whole string after the loop was ended. What's wrong here?

Python 2.7.9.

Comment: `from __future__ import print_function` and not `from __future__ import print` ?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments in the linked answer give the reason - `sys.stdout.flush()` is still needed to flush output buffer.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time

num = '\r'
for i in xrange(10):
    num += str(i+1) + ' '
    print (num, end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.3)
print('\n')
```